# Why am I unexpectedly able to create multiple instances of my singleton class?

Tags: java, design-patterns

As per my knowledge **Singleton Design Pattern** means we can only create one **SINGLE OBJECT** of a class.

The following code is running successfully without any error/exception.

I expect the code to fail because the `SingletonExample` class has a private default constructor.

```
public class SingletonExample {
    private static SingletonExample singletonInstance;

    private SingletonExample() {
    }

    public static SingletonExample getSingletonInstance() {
        if (null == singletonInstance) {
            System.out.println("Creating new instance");
            singletonInstance = new SingletonExample();
        }
        return singletonInstance;
    }

    public void printSingleton(){
        System.out.println("Inside print Singleton");
    }

    public static void main(String a[])  {
        SingletonExample singObj1 = new SingletonExample();
        SingletonExample singObj2 = new SingletonExample();
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You might want to check some other methods for singleton generation.  Double check locking isn't the best of them.

Comment: You are not even calling your `getSingletonInstance()` method that you made.

Comment: If you can do `new SingletonExample()`, it's not a Singleton.

Answer (score 23):

Because your `main` method is in the class `SingletonExample`, the `main` code can access the private constructor.

Try moving your `main` method to another class.

Answer (score 0):

Your calling singleton class's private constructor in same class so your able to access the constructor else you can't. Design patterns will define rules to avoid normal human errors only.

Answer (score 0):

the intent of the singleton pattern is to control the number of instances and you have done the correctly. only this class can make instances, so just make only one.

Answer (score 0):

Use enum instead of class. And no one will be able to replace your instance:

```
public enum SingletonExample {
    singletonInstance;

    private SingletonExample() {
        System.out.println("Creating new instance");          
    }

    public static void main(String a[])  {

    }
}
```